# wavelink node not connecting or creating pool

Tags: python, discord.py

so i'm sure many people in the discord py community know of robotic nation on youtube, alexa makes great tutorials i had folower their first music bot tutorial using youtubedl but as it now violated youtube terms of service they made a new tutorial using wavelink and lavalink with java 13, i’ve set it all up to spec per the tutorial but for some reason i keep getting errors about `no nodes in pool` even after the node pool should be configured correctly to spec from the video

i'm hosting my bot via a rpi4 compute and have java 13.0.1 installed along with wavelink for this project bellow are the codes used i’ve messaged alexa and tried to trouble shoot with them multiple times but they cant even spot the error either hopefully someomne here can spot it

lavalink.jar is a dependency used

application.yml

```yaml
server: # REST and WS server
  port: 2333
  address: 0.0.0.0
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "youshallnotpass"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      http: true
      local: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses
    frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true
    #ratelimit:
      #ipBlocks: ["1.0.0.0/8", "..."] # list of ip blocks
      #excludedIps: ["...", "..."] # ips which should be explicit excluded from usage by lavalink
      #strategy: "RotateOnBan" # RotateOnBan | LoadBalance | NanoSwitch | RotatingNanoSwitch
      #searchTriggersFail: true # Whether a search 429 should trigger marking the ip as failing
      #retryLimit: -1 # -1 = use default lavaplayer value | 0 = infinity | >0 = retry will happen this numbers times

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""
#  tags:
#    some_key: some_value
#    another_key: another_value

logging:
  file:
    max-history: 30
    max-size: 1GB
  path: ./logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: INFO
```

bot.py (section in question)

```py
@bot.command()
async def connect(ctx):
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    print("----begin debug log ??connect----")
    print("vc variable: "+str(vc))
    try:
        print("attempt to fetch channel author")
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        print("channel author: "+str(channel))
        print("after attempt to fetch channel author")
    except:
        print("attept to fetch exception AtributeError")
        return await ctx.send("please join a voice channel to connect.")
        print("after attept to fetch exception AtributeError")
        
    if not vc:
        print("before not vc")
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=CustomPlayer())
        print("after not vc")
    else:
        print("before else not vc")
        await ctx.send("the bot is already connected to a voice channel")
        print("after else not vc")
    print("----end connect debug log----")
```

the class that also seems to have shown issues in debug

```py
class CustomPlayer(wavelink.Player):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = wavelink.Queue()
```

the error code produced

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ZeroConnectedNodes: There are no connected Nodes on this pool.
```

after fixing the code a bit and accommodating the fact that loop is deprecated i still get this error log, i'm not sure why it just wont create nodes this is becoming quite frustrating

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
   await coro(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 79, in on_ready
   asyncio.run(main())
 File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 33, in run
   raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/client.py:416: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready.<locals>.main' was never awaited
 pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
[2022-09-18 16:54:14] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
   ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 234, in connect
   await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=CustomPlayer())
 File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 29, in __init__
   super().__init__()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/wavelink/player.py", line 89, in __init__
   node = NodePool.get_node()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/wavelink/pool.py", line 452, in get_node
   raise ZeroConnectedNodes("There are no connected Nodes on this pool.")
wavelink.errors.ZeroConnectedNodes: There are no connected Nodes on this pool.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
   await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
   await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
   raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ZeroConnectedNodes: There are no connected Nodes on this pool.
```

fixed code in question

```py
async def connect_nodes():
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(
            bot=bot,
            host='192.168.1.81',
            port=2333,
            password='JnG-330-qrsd')
    async def main():
        await connect_nodes() # again, no need to run with AbstractLoopEvent if you can await
        await bot.start(TOKEN)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

on another attempt on my current code i'm getting this error trying to launch the bot.py

```py
[H[2J[3J[1;33m launching...[0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 739, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 83, in main
    await connect_nodes() # again, no need to run with AbstractLoopEvent if you can await
  File "/home/pi/bot/bot.py", line 75, in connect_nodes
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 1108, in wait_until_ready
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Client has not been properly initialised. Please use the login method or asynchronous context manager before calling this method
[1;33m closed....[0m
```

i'm at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [create a node](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#wavelink.NodePool.create_node) with `wavelink` that handles the connection to `Lavalink`

```py
import wavelink
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot=bot,
                                        host='0.0.0.0',
                                        port=2333,
                                        password='YOUR_LAVALINK_PASSWORD')

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: I do have a connect nodes function i forgot to include it here but i don’t think it has a bot.loop so maybe that will fix it

Comment: when attempting this code update i get an error saying `loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async context`

Comment: It seems like `loop` was removed from `client` in version `2.0`. I've changed the code to create the node in the `on_ready` event. You can possibly have a look at [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) if you don't want to implement it within `on_ready`